# How to monitor docker services using elastic stack

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, docker-swarm, metricbeat

I have a docker swarm running a number of services. I'm using the elastic stack (kibana, elastic, filebeat, etc) for monitoring.
For the business logic I'm writing logs and using filebeat to move them to logstash and analyze the data in kibana.

But I'm having trouble in monitoring the liveness of my docker services. some of them are deployed globally (like filebeat) and some of them have a number of replicas. I wan't to be able to see in kibana that the number of running containers is equal to the number that the service should have.   I'm trying to use metricbeat with [docker module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-docker.html), the most useful metricset I've found is [`container`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-docker-container.html), but it doesn't seem to contain enough information for me to display or analyze the number of instances of a service.

I'd appreciate any advice how to achieve this.

*The metricbeat config*

```
metricbeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hits.enabled: true

metricbeat.modules:
  - module: docker
    enabled: true
    metricsets:
      - container
      - healthcheck
      - info
    period: 10s
    hosts: [ "unix:///var/run/docker.sock" ]

processors:
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_locale:
      format: offset

output.logstash:
  hosts: [ "mylogstash.com" ]
```

*The metricset `container` log data (the relevant docker part)*

```
...
"docker" : {
  "container": {
    "id": "60983ad304e13cb0245a589ce843100da82c5fv9e093aad68abb439cdc2f3044"
    "status": "Up 3 weeks",
    "command": "./entrypoint.sh",
    "image": "registry.com/myimage",
    "created": "2019-04-08T11:38:10.000Z",
    "name": "mystack_myservice.wuiqep73p99hcbto2kgv6vhr2.mufs70y24k5388jxv782in18f",
    "ip_addresses": [ "10.0.0.148" ]
    "labels" : {
       "com_dokcer_swarm_node_id": "wuiqep73p99hcbto2kgv6vhr2",
       "com_docker_swarm_task_name": "stack_service.wuiqep73p99hcbto2kgv6vhr2.mufs70y24k5388jxv782in18f",
       "com_docker_swarm_service_id": "kxm5dk43yzyzpemcbz23s21xo",
       "com_docker_swarn_task_id":  "mufs70y24k5388jxv782in18f",
       "com_docker_swarm_task" : "",
       "com_docker_stack_namespace": "mystack",
       "com_docker_swarm_service_name": "mystack_myservice"
     },
     "size": {
        "rw": 0,
        "root_fs": 0
     }
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:

I wrote a bash script which runs by interval and write a json log for each of the swarm services. the script is wrapped in image [docker service logger](https://cloud.docker.com/u/matanper/repository/docker/matanper/docker-service-logger)